# Can flow of gas be too strong to ignite in oven?

Tags: gas, oven

My Viking oven lights only intermittently.  I hear the spark module sparking.  It tries for 4 cycles and then turns off, to prevent explosions I assume.  I have replaced spark module once; no help.

When I take the metal floor of the oven off so I can look down and see the spark module and the gas manifold, it usually lights.  I see sparks.

It is hard for me to think of a reason it would light with floor off but not with floor on.  Could there be so much gas coming out that it replaces available O2 under the floor and so cannot light?  Ideas welcome.  I want to bake!

Answer (score 2):

I would speculate that the MIXTURE of gas and air may be off, in the "too much gas" direction. There are lower and upper limits of the gas to air mixture beyond which the mixture will not ignite (too little gas to light, or too little oxygen from air to light.) Removing the oven floor may provide just enough extra outside air to allow it to light.

Check the color of the flames - if they are more yellow than blue that's a pretty good sign the mixture is too rich. There is normally some sort of air control on/near the burner inlet. They are not too prone to move of themselves, but they more often get plugged up with dirt, hair, or spiderwebs. However, it may need adjusting if merely cleaning it does not solve your problem.

Comment: I like the idea of cleaning something to solve problems.  I did not know there was an air inlet for the burner.  I will find it and clean it.  Thank you!